# Parse JSON objects(lat and lng) in GoogleMap as markers

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps, gson

When I parse the lat and lng in *System.out.println(shop.getShopLat());* works fine. And the Map without marker works fine. Now I want to add several marker using shop.getShopLat() and shop.getShopLng(). But when I tried to implement this getting redflags: **The constructor LatLng(ArrayList, ArrayList) is undefined** Someone please help to solve this?

Comment: You clearly don't have a construtor that accepts two `ArrayList` arguments.

Comment: why I'm getting vote down? I asked a question that I don't know and I couldn't find the solution on google.

Comment: because the error clearly says what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this line:

```
for(Shop shop : this.response.shops){
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(shop.getShopLat(), shop.getShopLng())).title(shop.getShopAddress()));
            }
```

In this line you want to create a new LatLng() object by adding into constructor an array instead of one value, change this line into:

```
for(Shop shop : this.response.shops){
    //remember to check is shop.getShopLat() is not null etc..
    for(int i = 0; i < shop.getShopLat().size(); i++){
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng( shop.getShopLat().get(i), shop.getShopLng().get(i) )).title( shop.getShopAddress().get(i) ));
    }
}
```

Comment: I already identified where the error is and made the change similar to your answer, but now I got new redflag: The constructor LatLng(String, String) is undefined

Comment: You need: Double.parseDouble(shop.getShopLat().get(i)); if it is double value, if it is int then Integer.parseInteger(....